# ¿how to fix side menu functionality in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am working with Android Studio and I have a side menu, most of the options are working because I configure them in "mobile_navigation".
But I need one of my items to open a URL and I don't know how to do it.

My menu xml is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/profile"
            android:title="@string/menu_profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_web"
            android:icon="@drawable/web"
            android:title="@string/menu_web" />
    </group>
```

I handle the actions of the items like this:

```html
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:name="com.myApp.myApp.ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_profile_to_nav_fragment2"
            app:destination="@id/nav_correccion" />
    </fragment>
     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_web">
     </fragment>
```

Tried using onOptionsItemSelected (), but it still doesn't work for me. Please help

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        //navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_perfil, R.id.nav_web
        )
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id= item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(id==R.id.nav_web){
            Uri uri=Uri.parse("https://google.com.co");
            Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Tie destinations to menu items section](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer), Navigation uses the IDs you add to your menu xml, matching them to destinations in your navigation graph xml file.

So if you had a menu item such as

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_web"
    android:icon="@drawable/web"
    android:title="@string/menu_web" />
```

and wanted it to start a different activity, you could add an `<activity>` destination to your navigation graph:

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/nav_web"
    app:data="https://google.com.co"
    app:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

And because they have the same ID, your activity would be started when you click that item in your menu.